# FluentValidation pass parameter to WithMessage

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fluentvalidation

I have the following code in validator:

```
RuleFor(mb => mb.Amount).
Must((mb, amount) =>
                {
                   var betLimit = _battlesService.GetBetLimit(mb.BattleId);

                   mb.Amount <= betLimit;
                }).
WithMessage("Bet should be less than {0}", "bet limit value should be placed here");
```

Is there any way to pass betLimit value to WithMessage method? The only solution I see is to set betLimit value to some property of ViewModel and then access it in WithMessage overload with funcs. But it is ugly.

Answer (score 4):

Since `Amount` isn't used to get the `betLimit`, can't you pull the bet limit into a field when your validator fires up, and use it wherever you want?  Something like:

```
public ViewModelValidator(IBattlesService battlesService)
{
    var betLimit = battlesService.GetBetLimit();

    RuleFor(mb => mb.Amount).
    Must((mb, amount) =>
                    {
                       mb.Amount <= betLimit;
                    }).
    WithMessage(string.Format("Bet should be less than {0}", "bet limit value should be placed here", betLimit));
    ...
}
```

**UPDATE:**

I see now that you added the param from the view model.  Looks like you should be able to get to it like this, based on the third example in the FluentValidation docs [here](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Customising&referringTitle=Documentation&ANCHOR#CustomError):

```
    public ViewModelValidator(IBattlesService battlesService)
    {
        RuleFor(mb => mb.Amount).
        Must((mb, amount) =>
                        {
                           mb.Amount <= betLimit;
                        }).
        WithMessage("Bet should be less than {0}", mb => battlesService.GetBetLimit(mb.BattleId));
        ...
    }
```

Comment: Actually betLimit retrieval is based on some other properties of mb. I just tried to simplify an example and made it a bit wrong

Comment: But where does betLimit inside Must come from in your second example?

Comment: Ah my bad, I was focused on the WithMessage part.  Looks like you would have to hit that service twice.  If the two service roundtrips cause pain you could cache the result of that in the HttpContext...but I can't imagine there's a way to take something from the Must rule to communicate to the WithMessage call.